# Stream hex number as decimal

Tags: c, pi

I would like to use the BBP formula to calculate Pi in a C-program's pthread process while another process prints the result for as far as it has got. However BBP gives a base 16 answer while I would like to stream a base 10 answer to the user.

How can I determine whether it's safe to print the n-th digit of a base 10 converted base 16 number?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "*safe*" in which sense?

Comment: Not sure if that's possible. At any point of your program, if you decide to print out your digits, and the next value is a-f, the previous digits can all change, or at leats that's how it seems to me.

Comment: @alk: Let h[i] be the i-th hexadecimal digit of a number, numbered with h[0] being the least integer digit, h[-1] being the 1/16 digit, and so on, and let d[i] be the i-th decimal digit of the same number. We want to calculate d[i], which means we must know the value of the number well enough that further refinements to the value will not cause d[i] to change. For what j is knowing all the hexadecimal digits from h[infinity] down to h[j] sufficient?

Comment: Thanks for your answers. It is possible for me to wait printing until there is more certain about the number.

Comment: Streaming decimal digits from an input of hexadecimal digits is analogous to calling `push_back()` on a C++ `std::vector`. If you really wanted to "stream" it one-by-one, each additional digit will have linear cost to how many digits are already in. (Similar to resizing the vector after every call to `push_back()`.)

Comment: Using the best known algorithm, it's actually `O(N * log(N))` for each digit. But what you can do instead of streaming is to convert digits `0 - N` all at once using the `O(N * log(N)^2)` algorithm. Save all of it, and stream them one-by-one until you run out. Then you double the size and convert all digits `0 - 2N` and repeat. Just like an `std::vector`.

Comment: @Mysticial: That converts the problem from a base-16-to-base-10 algorithm to a base-16**N-to-base-10 algorithm. The question of knowing whether a particular base-10 digit will not change with more information remains.

Comment: @EricPostpischil You can't be absolutely sure in all cases. But they are rare and it's easy to tell if you're near them because your output will be like 9999999999. In which case a carryout from an (unknown) lower digit can push it over. So if you start getting a stream of 9's you hold off on the output until you stop getting 9's.

Comment: @Mysticial: Consider .1f in base 16. When we consider .1, the decimal value is .0625. There are no nines to be seen. Yet we cannot display any of these digits, since the next hexadecimal digit will reveal the decimal numeral to be .12109375.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I meant *after* converting to decimal. If after converting what you have to decimal results in `0.123999999`. Then you know not to trust the `3` until you have more hexadecimal digits to show that it will not carryout and turn the `3` into a `4`. (This is already assuming that you know the error is less than `10^-3`.)

Comment: @Mysticial: Consider hexadecimal 0x.1fb. Converted to decimal, this is 0.123779296875. The error, by which I presume you mean the most that remaining digits could change the value, is less than 10^-3 (it is about 0.0002441410). So, the criteria you have given us suggest we can display 0.123. However, the next hexadecimal digit is f, producing hexadecimal 0x.1fbf, decimal 0.1240081787109375.

Comment: @EricPostpischil So I was off by 1 or 2 orders of magnitude. Fine. How about something like `10^-10`. Correct me if I'm wrong, but there should be no room for `0.123xxxx` to become `0.1240000` if the error is `10^-10` unless `xxxx = 9999`. In practice, bignum libraries will go arbitrarily large margins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to test whether increasing the last hexadecimal digit currently available changes the decimal digit you are considering displaying.

Consider a number x with hexadecimal representation …h<sub>3</sub>h<sub>2</sub>h<sub>1</sub>h<sub>0</sub>.h<sub>-1</sub>h<sub>-2</sub>… and decimal representation …d<sub>3</sub>d<sub>2</sub>d<sub>1</sub>d<sub>0</sub>.d<sub>-1</sub>d<sub>-2</sub>…

Suppose we have a truncated numeral, so that we know only the digits from h<sub>∞</sub> to h<sub>j</sub>. Let y be the number represented by these digits. Let z be y + 16<sup>j</sup>, which is y plus one in the j digit position.
Then the value of x might be any value from y (inclusive) to z (exclusive).

Now consider a candidate decimal numeral, with digits d<sub>∞</sub> to d<sub>i</sub>. Let y' be the number represented by these digits. Let z' be y + 10<sup>i</sup>. Iff y' ≤ y and z ≤ z', then the decimal digits d<sub>∞</sub> to d<sub>i</sub> must be a prefix of the complete decimal numeral for x (that is, these decimal digits are known to appear in the decimal numeral for x; they will not change as more hexadecimal digits are discovered).

This is because the value of x, being in [y, z), can be formed by adding some zero or positive value to y' and that value needed is less than 1 in the i digit position. Conversely, if the inequalities do not hold, then x could be outside the interval spanned by the candidate digits.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is clear to me. I'll try to implement this and will look at chux answer to guide me.

Answer (score 1):

@Eric Postpischil posted a fine general purpose algorithm.

In implementing OP goal's, some short-cuts may be realized.
Handle the integer portion of Pi separate and only deal with the fraction.
Assume input is base 16 and then add 1 bit at a time.

Implementation notes:
I cheated by using fixed memory allocation and byte-array (string) handling.  Certainly one would save the array length rather than `strlen()` and use byte 0 - 9 rather than char '0' to '9', but this was tossed together quickly and was easier to debug this way.  Array size s/b dynamic, but that is easy to add.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
  char *Sum;
  char *Add;
} Pi_T;

void Pi_Print(const char *Title, Pi_T *State) {
  printf("%s\n", Title);
  printf("  Sum: '%s'\n", State->Sum);
  printf("  Add: '%s'\n", State->Add);
}

// Sum += Add
void Pi_Add(char *Sum, char *Add) {
  size_t LenS = strlen(Sum);
  size_t LenA = strlen(Add);
  while (LenS > LenA) {
    Add[LenA++] = '0';
    Add[LenA] = '\0';
  }
  while (LenA > LenS) {
    Sum[LenS++] = '0';
    Sum[LenS] = '\0';
  }
  unsigned Accumulator = 0;
  while (LenA > 0) {
    LenA--;
    Accumulator += Add[LenA] - '0';
    Accumulator += Sum[LenA] - '0';
    Sum[LenA] = Accumulator % 10 + '0';
    Accumulator /= 10;
    assert(Accumulator <= 9);
  }
  assert(Accumulator == 0);
}

// Divide the `Add` by 2
void Pi_Div2(char *Add) {
  size_t LenS = strlen(Add);
  size_t i;
  unsigned Accumulator = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < LenS; i++) {
    Accumulator += Add[i] - '0';
    Add[i] = Accumulator / 2 + '0';
    Accumulator %= 2;
    Accumulator *= 10;
    assert ((Accumulator == 0) ||  (Accumulator == 10));
  }
  if (Accumulator > 0) {
    Add[i++] = Accumulator / 2 + '0';
    Add[i] = '\0';
    Accumulator %= 2;
    Accumulator *= 10;
    assert(Accumulator == 0);
  }
}

void Pi_PutHex(Pi_T *State, unsigned HexDigit) {
  // Add HexDigit, 1 bit at a time.
  for (unsigned i = 4; i-- > 0;) {
    if (HexDigit & (1 << i)) {
      Pi_Add(State->Sum, State->Add);
    }
    // Should the Sum[0] be extracted?
    if (State->Add[0] == '0') {
      for (size_t i = 1; State->Sum[i] && State->Add[i]; i++) {
        unsigned Accumulator = State->Sum[i] - '0' + State->Add[i] - '0';
        if (Accumulator > 9)
          break;
        if (Accumulator < 9) {

          // !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
          // Print the decimal digit!
          printf("%c", State->Sum[0]);
          // !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

          memmove(&State->Sum[0], &State->Sum[1], strlen(State->Sum));
          memmove(&State->Add[0], &State->Add[1], strlen(State->Add));
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    Pi_Div2(State->Add);
  }
}

void Pi_Test(void) {
  Pi_T State;
  State.Sum = malloc(500);
  State.Add = malloc(500);
  State.Sum[0] = '\0';
  State.Add[0] = '5';
  State.Add[1] = '\0';
  // http://calccrypto.wikidot.com/math:pi-hex
  static const char *pi = "3.243F6A8885A308D313198A2E03707344A4093822299F31D0082EFA98EC4E6C89452821E638D01378";
  // http://www.miniwebtool.com/first-n-digits-of-pi/?number=100
  // 3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445923078164062862089986280348253421170679
  // Output
  // 3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592307816406286208998628034825342117
  const char *p = &pi[2];
  // Pi_Print("Init", &State);
  printf("3.");
  // add each hex digit, one at a time.
  while (*p) {
    unsigned HexDigit = (*p <= '9')  ? (*p - '0') : (*p - 'A' + 10);

    // !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    // Put in the hexadecimal digit
    Pi_PutHex(&State, HexDigit);
    // !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

    p++;
  }
  printf("\n");
  // Pi_Print("End", &State);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, this will certainly guide me through.